# Single word when you know destination but not path

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, terminology, slang

Is there a single word which describes knowing the destination but not the path?

Knowing the objective but not the method?

Knowing the 'what' or 'where' but not the 'how'?

In a sense this would be the antonym for coddiwomple where the destination is vague, but the steps are purposeful.

Thanks much.

Comment: From an OED editor, 2017, via [OxfordDictionaries](https://forum.oxforddictionaries.com/en/discussion/12/coddiwomple): 'I am slightly suspicious that almost all occurrences of _coddiwomple_ give it the same definition word for word, rather than simply using the verb in a natural sentence, which suggests to me that this may be a relatively recent invention which has caught on to a certain extent online. That doesn’t make it any less of a “real word” necessarily, but for the OED’s purposes,...

Comment: it’s probably a little too recent for us to include at the moment, unless more evidence comes to light. We like to be sure that a word is properly established in the English language with a reasonable amount of currency before we include it in the OED.' ELU, where the U stands for usage, adopts this approach.

Comment: **coddiwomple** seems to be an invented word. It claims to be "slang" and there 3 entries in Urban Dictionary. It also appears generally on the internet, but always with exactly the same definition *To travel in a purposeful manner towards a vague destination.* which indicates that it has been copied rather than used. You seem therefore to be attempting to find a word related to a word that has no currency - other than as an "invented word" - possibly from someone's idiolect. (Crossposted with Edwin A)

Comment: It's very common to know the destination but not the route (every time you start up Google Maps or open a road atlas or A-Z or ask for directions you are in this state), while the opposite is rarer. Various phrases such as "being lost" or "goal-oriented" describe your state, although probably none are unambiguous enough to quite match it. It seems something so mundane that nobody has bothered to invent a word for it, but maybe I'll be proven wrong.

Comment: You could have a ***vision*** of the outcome without knowing how that vision will be realized.

Comment: Not one word but a non-geographical aim (like "I want to be a multi-millionaire") is an _aspirational goal_. More often than people have _aspirational goals_ before adopting routes to achieving  them.

Comment: I agree with Stuart F here. I also tried to find a word that would fit what you are asking for but there seems to be no such word.